# Forward SIGTERM to child in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, signals, docker

I have a Bash script, which looks similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Doing some initial work....";
/bin/start/main/server --nodaemon
```

Now if the bash shell running the script receives a SIGTERM signal, it should also send a SIGTERM to the running server (which blocks, so no trap possible). Is that possible?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash 

_term() { 
  echo "Caught SIGTERM signal!" 
  kill -TERM "$child" 2>/dev/null
}

trap _term SIGTERM

echo "Doing some initial work...";
/bin/start/main/server --nodaemon &

child=$! 
wait "$child"
```

Normally, `bash` will ignore any signals while a child process is executing. Starting the server with `&` will background it into the shell's job control system, with `$!` holding the server's PID (to be used with `wait` and `kill`). Calling `wait` will then wait for the job with the specified PID (the server) to finish, *or for any signals to be fired*.

When the shell receives `SIGTERM` (or the server exits independently), the `wait` call will return (exiting with the server's exit code, or with the signal number + 128 in case a signal was received). Afterward, if the shell received SIGTERM, it will call the `_term` function specified as the SIGTERM trap handler before exiting (in which we do any cleanup and manually propagate the signal to the server process using `kill`).

Comment: But [exec replaces the shell with the given program](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec), I am not clear on why the subsequent `wait` call is then needed?

Comment: @1_CR: `wait` need for our script to ... wait for child process to finish. We want to be sure that our script only quit after child process is terminated.

Comment: I think that 1_CR's point is valid. Either you simply use `exec /bin/start/main/server --nodaemon` (in which case the shell process is replaced with the server process and you don't need to propagate any signals) or you use `/bin/start/main/server --nodaemon &`, but then `exec` is not really meaningful.

Comment: @1_CR and @Andreas are correct - I've removed the `exec` from mid-script, so the Bash process will remain around the server process for cleanup on signal.

Comment: Also,  `exec` is a perfectly reasonable solution for the problem as the original question was asked; I've submitted it as a separate answer, and clarified what this answer does instead.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley: The point here is using `exec command &` will start command in a subshell and in new shell `exec` will replace the shell with the main program. I don't remember when the last edit remove exec part, make my explanation incorrect.

Comment: If you want your shell script to terminate only after child is terminated, then in the `_term()` function you should `wait "$child"` again. This might be necessary if you have some other supervising process waiting for the shell script to die before restarting it again, or if you also trapped `EXIT` to do some cleanup and neeed it to run only after the child process has finished.

Comment: I think `bash` ignores SIGTERM only in `interactive` mode according to `man` and my local testing. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: SURELY there is a FLAG we can set in Bash to this for us? For example, `set -o forwardsignals`, or whatever

Comment: @AlexanderMills Read the other answers. Either you're looking for [`exec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196053/7733), or you want to [set up traps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444676/7733).

Comment: thanks @StuartP.Bentley I missed that until you mentioned it

Comment: The script as it is written is racy. If TERM will be sent righter after bash started the background job but before `child=$! `, the child is not set and the kill reports error. To fix the trap handler should just use `$!`

Comment: @IgorBukanov and what happens if TERM is sent right BEFORE bash starts the background job?  See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444676/285587) for a full solution.

Comment: This script works on SIGTERM but not on SIGQUIT because shell ignores SIGQUIT in background child process.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45106725/921859

Comment: This tricks makes "podman stop" works properly if the container uses a start.sh to run his daemon. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 149):

Bash does not forward signals like SIGTERM to processes it is currently waiting on. If you want to end your script by *segueing into* your server (allowing it to handle signals and anything else, as if you had started the server directly), you should use `exec`, which will *replace the shell with the process being opened*:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Doing some initial work....";
exec /bin/start/main/server --nodaemon
```

If you need to keep the shell around for some reason (ie. you need to do some cleanup after the server terminates), you should use a combination of `trap`, `wait`, and `kill`. See [SensorSmith's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444676/7733).

Comment: This is the correct answer! So much more concise and addresses OP's original ask exactly

Comment: I was pretty happy about the accepted answer because `exec` has one limitation: You replace the process image, so you are not able to execute code after the process exits (e.g. cleanup, which was important for me).

Answer (score 54):

[Andreas Veithen points out](http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html) that if you do not need to return from the call (like in the OP's example) simply calling through the `exec` command is sufficient ([@Stuart P. Bentley's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196053/285587)).  Otherwise the "traditional" `trap 'kill $CHILDPID' TERM` (@cuonglm's answer) is a start, but the `wait` call actually returns after the trap handler runs which can still be before the child process actually exits.  So an "extra" call to `wait` is advisable ([@user1463361's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434269/285587)).

While this is an improvement it still has a race condition which means that the process may never exit (unless the signaler retries sending the TERM signal).  The window of vulnerability is between registering the trap handler and recording the child's PID.

The following eliminates that vulnerability (packaged in functions for reuse).

```
prep_term()
{
    unset term_child_pid
    unset term_kill_needed
    trap 'handle_term' TERM INT
}

handle_term()
{
    if [ "${term_child_pid}" ]; then
        kill -TERM "${term_child_pid}" 2>/dev/null
    else
        term_kill_needed="yes"
    fi
}

wait_term()
{
    term_child_pid=$!
    if [ "${term_kill_needed}" ]; then
        kill -TERM "${term_child_pid}" 2>/dev/null 
    fi
    wait ${term_child_pid} 2>/dev/null
    trap - TERM INT
    wait ${term_child_pid} 2>/dev/null
}

# EXAMPLE USAGE
prep_term
/bin/something &
wait_term
```

Comment: Excellent job - I've updated the link in my answer to point here (on top of this being a more comprehensive solution, I'm still a little irked that the StackExchange UI doesn't credit me in cuonglm's answer for [fixing the script to actually do what it's supposed to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/146770/4) and [writing pretty much all the explanatory text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/146770/5) after the OP [who didn't even understand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146756/forward-sigterm-to-child-in-bash/196053#comment328666_146770) made a few minor re-edits).

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley, thanks.  I _was_ surprised assembling this required two (not accepted) answers and an external reference, and then I had to run down the race condition.  I will upgrade my references to links as what little additional kudos I can give.

Comment: Is this solution Bash-only?

Comment: @TorstenBronger it _should_ be portable, but I haven't tested it under anything but Bash.  I did not use any deliberate Bashisms (no 'function' keyword, no double brace conditionals, no fancy tricks in the output redirection, and the trap syntax is Posix).

Comment: However, this only works if the child is guaranteed not to exit (on purpose or on error). Then, the second `wait` throws an error.

Comment: @TorstenBronger re-tested under Ubuntu 18.04 Bash 4.4.20 (not my original target) and get Bash debug-ish output with line # and "Terminated", but when the child had NOT exited prior to the trap (odd).  It might be legal for the PID to be forgotten after the first wait, but the 2nd wait IS necessary on some systems, so no good answer.  (Exit code was still available in this test.)  I edited to redirect the "error" output to null for when/systems on which it happens.

Comment: I saw no other way but to assume that the child never exits with 143 or 130 (unless signal was sent). I documented it cleanly, and recommended to wrap it in a subshell if it does.

Comment: At https://gist.github.com/bronger/acce7736141b3fa118b0d47f1a2035ac#file-signal_propagation-sh-L45 you see what was necessary in my case (zsh). It still does not cover all edge cases, but they might be considered programming errors anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Provided solution doesn't work for me because process was killed before the wait command actually finished. I found that article http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html, the last snippet work good in my case of application started in the OpenShift with custom sh runner. The sh script is required because I need to have an ability to get thread dumps which is impossible in case PID of Java process is 1.

```
trap 'kill -TERM $PID' TERM INT
$JAVA_EXECUTABLE $JAVA_ARGS &
PID=$!
wait $PID
trap - TERM INT
wait $PID
EXIT_STATUS=$?
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a few points to the above answers:

1. Starting the process in the background with '&' and wait for its pid as advised by [@cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146756/forward-sigterm-to-child-in-bash/146770#146770) will make it possible for the handler to execute while the child is running, but the child will loose the ability to catch any input as stdin will be closed as soon as the child is detached. To force stdin to stay open, you might add an infinite loop which you pipe to the child process. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575473/running-a-process-that-waits-on-input-in-the-background-without-it-pausing-and#answer-9576436).

Then read input in the current shell and write it to the proc file of the child's process so it goes to its stdin:

```
(while true; do sleep 10000; done) | /bin/start/main/server --nodaemon &
child_pid=$!
while :
do
    result=$(kill -0 $mypid > /dev/null 2>&1)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        # process is gone
        break
    else
        # read input in the current shell and store it in a variable. The timeout only works with Bash, not with Bourne-Shell. You will need to find a way to read stdin instead and sleep 1 sec between each loop
        read -t 1 input 
        
        # echo the input to the proc file of the runuser process so it goes to its stdin
        echo $input > /proc/$child_pid/fd/0 2>/dev/null 
    fi
done
wait $child_pid
```

NOTE: this works pretty well on Linux but might need some adjustments for other Unix platforms.

**EDIT**: a simpler method is to duplicate stdin to a file descriptor which can then be used as the stdin for the background process:

```
exec 3<&0
/bin/start/main/server --nodaemon <&3 &
```

2. exec is the second solution as suggested by @[Stuart P. Bentley](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196053/285587), but sometimes you need to create the process with a new PID or the command used might not let you the choice and create the process with a new PID or even a new PGID (that's the case for example for runuser with the -l option).
3. An alternative to 1) and 2) is to send the signal to the process group instead of targeting a specific PID.

This can be done by using kill with a minus (-) before the child's PID:

```
kill -TERM -$child_pid
```

Bash will indeed let you trap signals that are targeting a process group without needing to start the process in the background. This method will not loose the ability for the child process to read stdin. This is also a good solution if your child is running in a different process group as the handler will let you forward the signal to the child. Limitation is that other members of the group will also receive the signal, which might be a problem or not depending on the scenario.