# How to `exec` process with custom env?

Tags: bash, exec

I'm [programmatically spawning processes in bash](https://github.com/schneems/wait_for_it/blob/bb3e7e83b13f20f6a4f745b53ae642d242e84cab/lib/wait_for_it.rb#L156-L158). I need to be able to pass in arbitrary environment variables and commands. To achieve this I'm running `/usr/bin/env` and then calling `bash -c`. Sometimes the process I started doesn't stop and I want to kill it, however when I kill the PID that comes back from my command, it only kills the bash command and not the the child process that bash ran.

I've seen [Forward SIGTERM to child in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146756/forward-sigterm-to-child-in-bash) so I think the problem can be fixed with bash `exec` however I can't invoke the correct command.

For example here is a ruby script that never exits:

```
STDOUT.sync = true

puts "booted"

while true
  puts "running"
  sleep 1
end
```

When I run it via `$ exec ruby spec/fixtures/never_exits.rb`, the program behaves as I want. When I kill my bash session the program is terminated.

However when I try to run this with `env` like `$ /usr/bin/env bash -c exec ruby spec/fixtures/never_exits.rb`, the command exits immediately and there's no output. It doesn't look like the script is being invoked.

Is it possible to use `exec` in combination with specifying environment variables?

Is there another way to propagate the TERM to a child process that could be invoked in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `bash -c` type structures you need to put the whole command inside `"` characters.
e.g

```
$ bash -c echo hello

$ bash -c "echo hello"
hello
```

So in your case

```
env bash -c "exec ruby script.rb"
```

However, the `env` in this example doesn't really do much; did you mean `env -i` to create an initial environment?  Also, unless there's some magic happening inside the bash startup scripts, you may not need bash at all.

```
 env -i RUBYPATH=/some/dir RUBYLIB=/other/dir /path/to/ruby script.rb
```

Comment: I left out the args to `/usr/bin/env` in this example for clarity. In the libary people can specify arbitrary env vars which is a hard requirement even though I didn't need them to demonstrate this failing case. That worked, thanks!